# Higher dimensional Derivatives Spivak

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm reading the differentiation chapter in Spivak calc on manifolds and struggling to understand the fundamentals.

Let's say we have a function $f(x, y) = xy$. Then $Df(a, b)$, the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $a$, is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then $Df(a, b)(x, y)$ is well-defined. But we can also write $f'(x, y) = [y, x]$.

Would I be correct in saying $f'(x, y) = [y, x]$ is the derivative of $f$ which only exists if $f$ is everywhere differentiable and is different from the Jacobian? We would need to evaluate $f'(x, y)$ at a point $(a, b)$ to get the Jacobian of $f$ at $(a, b)$? Why does Spivak make a point of computing $f'(a, b)$ instead of $f'(x, y)$?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to this :)

Comment: The Jacobian of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ at a point is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. So in your case, it’s a 1x2 matrix, not a 2x2 matrix. For functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the Jacobian coincides with the gradient. Also, the actual map changes depending on $(x,y)$, so when you think of the Jacobian as a linear map, don’t think of points $(x,y)$ as the inputs, think of vectors as inputs, acted upon by matrix multiplication.

Comment: @kieransquared the jacobian is the adjoint of the gradient

Comment: @AndrewZhang Doesn’t that depend on whether you think of the gradient as a vector or a linear map (“column vector or row vector”)? here I’m referring to it as the latter

Comment: I don't follow @kieransquared. It would be very weird to identify the jacobian as a vector. Anyhow, since you are identifying it as a linear map, there is then a distinction between column and row vectors, i.e. the Jacobian is not the same as the gradient.

Comment: I am treating the gradient as a row vector in my comment above, and hence identifying it with a linear map acting on (column) vectors. This is really just a matter of convention, as some texts define the gradient as a row vector. I’d argue this is geometrically natural; the gradient as a tangent vector wouldn’t even be well-defined on a manifold without a metric, as there would be no way to construct a vector from the differential.